# how to set image width dynamically in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8.1

I want to set  width to dynamically added button background image.

this is my code

```
Buttob btn=new Button();
 ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
 brush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-px:///Assets/emptyseat.jpg"));
   btn.Background = brush1;
```

how to set width of the above image dynamically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24684125/3279496

Comment: @nelek I want only set the  image  width.How can I set?

Comment: try this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142802/get-device-screen-resolution-in-windows-phone-8-1-xaml

Comment: everywhere find same answer ... :(

Comment: Are you trying to make it as wide as the button? You can use Stretch property.

Answer (score 2):

You can *scale* the image by creating a [ScaleTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform(v=vs.110).aspx) object and applying it to the imageBrush, and setting the Stretch property on your brush to whatever it is you desire.

For example:

```
        Button btn = new Button();
        ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();            
        brush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/emptyseat.jpg"));

        ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        scaleTransform.ScaleX = 0.5;
        brush1.Transform = scaleTransform;
        brush1.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

        btn.Background = brush1;
```

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve but the above will resize the image for you.