# Screen size and RAM on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, ram, screen-size

How do I block a specific screen size on windows phone 8.1? is there a way?
And how to set the minimum ram on windows phone 8.1?

Edit: 
I mean is: "block size under 4-inch screen can not download the application from the Windows store. And the purpose of giving the RAM limit is for under 1 GB RAM can not download applications from the store windows as well. How to?"

Answer (score 0):

You can check RAM limit via:

```
static int MemoryLimitMB { get { return (int) MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit / 1024 / 1024; } }
```

Question on screen size has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142802/get-device-screen-resolution-in-windows-phone-8-1-xaml).

Comment: What the meaning 0f 1024?
not to get the screen resolution, but to block size under 4-inch screen can not download the application from the Windows store. And the intention of giving limit for RAM is 1 GB RAM under can not download applications from the store windows as well. How to?

Comment: Dividing by 1024 twice converts bytes to megabytes. Not sure if you can prevent downloads based on RAM limit and/or screen size.